# Peut-on séparer les deux mots de « parce que » dans une phrase ?

Tags: conjonctions, locutions

L'autre jour, mon ami utilise une phrase avec la conjonction « parce que » mais avec les deux mots séparés, mais plus intéressant les deux sont ensemble plus tard, comme ici:

> Parce ... , que ... parce que ...

J'ai oublié ce qu'il a dit. Mon ami n'est pas un francophone, mais il a utilisé une service de traduction (*Google Translate*) pour cette phrase.

Je pense que « parce que » c'est toujours ensemble, ce n'est jamais séparé.

Peut-on séparer ces deux mots ou non?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *[Parce que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parce%20que)* est une locution conjonctive marquant une relation causale. On peut remplacer la locution par *À cause de*.

Parce que donne une explication, dit la cause d'une relation.
C'est une entrée du dictionnaire, elle correspond a un mot ; même si une espace la coupe en deux, on ne peut séparer les deux parties de ce mot.

> *[Par ce que](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/parce_que/58074/difficulte)* n'est pas reconnu comme entrée du dictionnaire, le *ce* peut être remplacé par *cela*, on peut remplacer l'expression par *Du fait de*.

Il semblerait qu'on utilise plus facilement *parce que* avec ce qui concerne l'être d'une personne et *par ce que* pour ce qui concerne ses avoirs dans des écrits très soutenus :

> Il me déplaît *parce qu'il **est*** superficiel
>   Il me déplaît *par ce qu'il **a*** de superficiel [dans son caractère, son attitude].

Remarquez qu'ils ne sont pas interchangeables sans modification de la structure de la phrase qui les supporte.

Les  *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parce%20que%2C%20par%20ce%20qu%27%2C%20par%20ce%20que&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparce%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0)* (2 siècles) et *[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parce%20que%2Cpar%20ce%20qu%27%2Cpar%20ce%20que&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparce%20que%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20ce%20qu%20%27%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpar%20ce%20que%3B%2Cc0)* (5 siècles) confirment votre intuition : il est  d'usage d'utiliser *parce que* sans se poser de question, et de réserver *par ce que* aux expressions littéraires recherchées.

*Par... ce... que*... peut être trouvé éparpillé dans une phrase, mais ce ne sera pas une locution, et le sens peut être complètement différent.

Comment: Quel est le motif du vote négatif ?